# Why doesn't this code work?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I was trying to put the following code to my website in order to get the number of Linkedin followers(Taken from the linkedin itself). However, it works perfectly on their website "preview" section.

**CODE:**

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="9223418" data-counter="right"></script>
```

Comment: maybe you are missing a `http:` here: `src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"`?

Comment: Tried, but still doesn't work...

Comment: Does it gives an error in your Javascript console (Ctrl+Shift+J)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the protocol for the source (in this case, http):

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="9223418" data-counter="right"></script>
```

Comment: Tried doing this
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="9223418" data-counter="right"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised The LinkedIN official SDK [getting started page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk) still has this error so I can see why you do it without the protocol...

Per others, you need to add the protocol but it should be "https" as opposed to "http".

Also, I believe you would need to specific you API key (a.k.a. Client ID). According to the documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
 api_key:   [API_KEY]
 onLoad:    [ONLOAD]
 authorize: [AUTHORIZE]
 lang:      [LANG_LOCALE]
</script>
```